GCloud Local Server Setup (dev_appserver.py)
I've been trying to set the GCloud local development server up with php82 but is unsuccessful.
I've installed Google Cloud SDK version 496.0.0 (latest) and Python 3.9.5 but it return the following error:
dev_appserver.py: error: the following arguments are required: yaml_path


The third screenshot shows the error after implementing @NoCommandline's answer

The error is very clear and it even says the argument required. Have you tried that?

@Puteri The required yaml_path is there but somehow, it doesn't recognizes it

In the first screenshoot you're only setting the port and that's all. I don't see any command where you're setting it.

@Puteri The "." you see there is the yaml_path which means - current directory. I've also tried the full path (C:\koboapp) but same result

. or C:\koboapp is a directory. The command expects a path to the yaml file e.g. C:\koboapp\app.yaml
Per the documentation

specifies one or more app.yaml files, one per service, for the positional argument yaml_path


I just ran: python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py" \koboapp\app.yaml --port 9090 --php_executable_path \php82\php-cgi.exe and the result is the third screenshot attached

I think your code has a bug. Your app actually started (see the line that said - starting module default running at..). Your error says not expecting type class 'list'. Check your code/try running a simple hello world app. Also, you ran your command from within your python directory - you shouldn't do that. I suggest you either run your command from your C root or run it from your project(app) directory and be consistent in how you specify paths. Also, if you added dev_appserver.py and your python executable to your PATH, you don't have to specify their full path.
